# Bootstrap3 select change expand icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can anyone tell me how to change expand icon in bootstrap3 selects?
I want to get something like in the second selects instead of standard expand icon
[image]

I know about ready solutions like this: [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

But I can't used it because they are messing with my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `appearance:none;` to your `select class` and add custom background.

Like

```
select {
/*other styles if any*/
display: inline-block;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none;
appearance:none;
border:solid 1px #CCC;
background: url("path/to/arrow.png") center right;
}
```